# Proving the existence of a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that exists a subgroup $H'$ such that $H\cup H' = \mathbb{Z}$ and if $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup there is no group $H'$ such that $H \oplus H' = \mathbb{Z}$.

It seems to me that the second assertion can be knocked off more easily than the first one. If $H\oplus H'=\mathbb{Z}$ then $H\cap H' = \varnothing$ and $H\cup H'=\mathbb{Z}$, but the neutral element $e$ doesn't have to belong to both $H$ and $H'$, then can't be $H\cap H'= \varnothing$ the the sum isn't direct. The argument would convince me, but problem with what I'm saying is that I'm not using the fact that $H$ is non-trivial, then the assertion holds for the trivial group too?.

Regarding the first question, I'm unsure of what would be a proper answer. I believe that the group could be simply defined as follows: let $H'_1$ all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ which are not in $H$ and $H'_2=\{y:y\cdot x =e \text{ for some }x\in H\}$ being $e$ the neutral element; then define $H'=H_1'\cup H_2'\cup\{e\}$. By the way it was defined, $H'$ satisfies the properties needed to be a subgroup and satisfies $H\cup H' = \mathbb{Z}$. Is this correct solution?.

Comment: I mean, let $H'=\Bbb Z$, it's the only way you're going to get $1$ anyways, there is no way to get a disjoint group, though, since any group with $1$ must be all of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of itself, the only way that $H\cup H'$ could be a subgroup is if $H\subseteq H'$ or $H'\subseteq H$. And in those cases you get that either $H=\Bbb Z$ or $H'=\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant $\;\Bbb Z= H\oplus H'\implies H\cap H'=\{0\}\neq\emptyset\;$ : the intersection of *any* two subgroups of **any** group cannot be empty as both subgroups contain *at least* the group's identity.

Now, the subgroups of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ are all of the form $\;m\Bbb Z\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and from here that

$$m,n\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;m\Bbb Z\cap n\Bbb Z=\left(l.c.m.(m,n)\right)\Bbb Z\neq\{0\}$$

so the sum of two non-trivial subgroups of the integer cannot be direct.

For the first question it is enough to take $\;H'=\Bbb Z\;$ ...